# DataReader cursor rewind

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqldatareader, database-cursor

How do I can rewind a cursor of a DataReader to the beginning?

With one DataReader result I need to run two `while` loop, but those have to be from beginning. They are two iterations in one result set running a query once.

Example:

```
dr = command.ExecuteReader(cmd);

while (dr.Read()) { 
    // do some...
}

// rewind cursor here

while (dr.Read()) {
    // do another things...
}
```

I've looked into the DataReader docs and I've found nothing, so if it can't be possible with DataReader, I may change the class for one that fits this purpose.

Comment: Run `ExecuteReader` again, that puts it back at the start :)

Comment: @Andomar but doing that will run the query again on database?

Comment: Yeah.  That's typically not a problem though.  Unless your code runs very frequently or comes with an exceptionally high load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (unless you execute the command again): it is a one-way stream. If you want to see the data more than once you'll have to buffer it in memory yourself, for example in a `List<T>` (for some `T`), or (yeuch) as a `DataTable`.

Comment: There's no another class for doing that?

Comment: That adds code complexity, and the memory requirement for holding all the rows client-side.  Might be worth it, but in many cases it's fine to run the query twice.

Comment: @Andomar and I would say that in the vast majority of cases, the memory is trivial compared to the network / rdbms latency.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown loading data into something you can query is trivial. Heck, with dapper it can be just `var data = conn.Query("some sql").ToList()`, which gives you `dynamic` access to columns, or `conn.Query<SomeType>("some sql").ToList()` if you are happy to define a `SomeType`. With `DataTable` it would be just `someTable.Load(reader)`. How is this work?

Comment: Agreed, "it depends".  In many cases performance doesn't matter at all and the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method that runs those queryes may be fast, It will be called with some frequency. So performance is relevant.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown then buffering it in memory for a moment is likely to be your best option. The other thing you could do is refactor the code so that you can do everything in one pass.

Comment: I'll try buffering then using `List` as you suggested. I'm afraid that I have no escape from that cause I'm depending on the data that let me no choices for doing that in one pass. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It worked. I've loaded the DataReader in a DataTable to have a parallel iteration. Worked fine.