# SqlDataReader showing Enumeration yielded no result

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

am trying to read the data using SqlDataReader.

But during execution of this code reader shows "Enumeration yielded no results".

```
 string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string sql = null;
            SqlDataReader reader;

            connetionString = "Data Source=INBAGHPC00840;Initial Catalog=Testing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345";
            sql = "select * from [Category]";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read()) //Here reader shows : Enumeration yielded no results
                {


                  // MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(0) + " - " + reader.GetValue(1) + " - " + reader.GetValue(2));
                }
                reader.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
```

I couldn't quite get what I am missing here. Please let me know..

Comment: For a start, we are missing the code which "shows no results".

Comment: There are no records, i.e. reader.HasRows will be false. Double check the table has data.

Comment: reader.HasRows showing true.  and table has the 7 rows.

Comment: Where do you get that error message? The catch block is empty, the while loop has no code. Can you explain better how this code fails?

Comment: the control went to check while (reader.Read()) --> Here reader shows : Enumeration yielded no results.so control jump to  reader.Close(); line....

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041745/sqldatareader-reader-read-shows-enumeration-yielded-no-results