# I want to add a new object into the list. Can someone explain how to do this?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add multiple objects to a list (`tmpUsers`) but when I try to add the second object I get into the catch block? Can someone see if I am doing it the right way and help me understand where I am going wrong?

```
public List<User> GetFilteredUsers(long CompanyKey, int sitekey, int filtertype=4, string filtervalue="", UserRequestContext requestContext = null)
{
    List<User> tmpUsers = new List<User>();

    Database db = null;
    IDataReader dr = null;
    DbCommand dbCommand = null;

    try
    {
        db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("vaultDataConfiguration");
        dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetFilteredUsers");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@CompanyKey", DbType.Int32, CompanyKey);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Sitekey", DbType.Int32, sitekey);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FilterType", DbType.Int32, filtertype);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FiterValue", DbType.String, filtervalue);
        dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
        User tmpUser = new User();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            
            tmpUser.GroupName = dr["groupName"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["groupName"].ToString() : "";
            tmpUsers.Add(tmpUser);
        }
        tmpUser = new User();
        tmpUser.CompanyUdidDescription = dr["companyUDIDDescription"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["companyUDIDDescription"].ToString() : "";
        tmpUsers.Add(tmpUser);
        return tmpUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogWriter.WriteAuditLog(ex.Message, LogLevel.ERROR, exception: ex, _event: "UserDAO->GetFilteredUserDetails", requestContext: requestContext);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Add user is happening out of While loop. Not sure how / when you get to adding second user

Comment: You presumably want to create a new `User` object for each record in the database, set its `GroupName` and `CompanyUdidDescription` properties from the database, and add the `User` object to the list, right? You really should move the line `User tmpUser = new User();;` inside the `while` loop, along with the code after the `while` loop, before the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read after the readers recors are over. Try this code

```
 
 while (dr.Read())
{
  var tmpUser = new User();                   
  tmpUser.GroupName = dr["groupName"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["groupName"].ToString() : "";
 tmpUser.CompanyUdidDescription = dr["companyUDIDDescription"] != DBNull.Value ? 
 dr["companyUDIDDescription"].ToString() : "";
 tmpUsers.Add(tmpUser);
}
return tmpUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to assign `tmpUser.CompanyUdidDescription`, you've already gotten to the end of your `DataReader`, but you are still trying to read from it.

You can't do that.

See: [DataReader cursor rewind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522541/datareader-cursor-rewind)